# Is there any replacement of "zones" in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linear-gradients

Currently what i am using for my highcharts column color is something like

```
series: [{
        name: 'Hello',
        data: [
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
        ],
         zonesAxis: 'y',
            zones: [{
                value: 1,
                color: '#00e600',
            }, {
                value: 1.5,
                color: ' #b3ff1a',
            }, {
                value: 3,
                color: '#ff9933',
            }, {
                value: 5,
                color: ' #ff5c33',
            }]

    }]
```

in this way I have to specify everytime the upperbound for which a particular color should be used.
what i want to do is just specify the upper bound and two colors.and the chart columns itself changes from one color to other gradually based on the value (not exactly but kind of linear gradient for different values cuz a column will have a definite colour not a linear gradient)

Answer (score 0):

got my answer

```
 colorAxis: {
      minColor: '#c6e48b',
      maxColor: '#196127',
      min: 0,
      max: 6,
      gridLineWidth: 0
  },
```

this helped